# iptables port forwarding to server with different port

Tags: iptables, smtp, port-forwarding

I am trying to port forward from one server to another. I have tried numerous iptables commands but they don't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my setup:

- VPS1: 1.1.1.1

  - SMTP Port : 25
  - UFW: OFF
  - iptables policy: Accept All
  - Hostname: mailbox.xxxxxx.com
  - OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Mail Server: 2.2.2.2

  - SMTP NAT Port: 15324

---

I have tried these commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:15324
iptables -A FORWARD -d 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 15324 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

> iptables -t nat -nvL
>
> Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 459 packets, 17802 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>      19  1088 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 to:2.2.2.2:15324
>
> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 120 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>      39  2603 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

After running a telnet to port 25 on the external IP I get this. The packet count changes so it is getting something, but I don't know why it isn't going through PREROUTING

> Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 469 packets, 18178 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>      19  1088 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25 to:2.2.2.2:15324
>
> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 180 bytes)
>    pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>      42  2812 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

---

Trying to telnet shows me this.

> telnet 2.2.2.2 15324
>   Trying 2.2.2.2...
>   Connected to 2.2.2.2.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   220 mailbox.xxxxxx.com ESMTP Hi, I'm a Mail-in-a-Box (Ubuntu/Postfix; see https://mailinabox.email/)
>
> telnet mailbox.xxxxxx.com 25
>   Trying 1.1.1.1...
>   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Bad downvote IMO.  This is a good post.

Comment: It's one of those unfortunate cases where the asker tried to post what they thought was relavent information but the actual problem had absolutely nothing to do with the information the asker thought was relevant, so the question is of limited utility for future visistors :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Damn it. I fixed it like a min after posting this. Solution:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: better use `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`